# AFNetworking 2: Authorization header not included in request

Tags: ios, http-headers, afnetworking-2

I have an app that uses AFNetworking 2. I am trying to make a request with an Authorization header. Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
NSURL                         *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:WLAPIBaseURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:email password:password];
[manager GET:WLAPIEndpointMe parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 }];
```

When I make the request, I get a 401 response. I monitored the request with Charles, and it turns out that the Authorization header is not included in the request...

I am sure this is not a problem with the server because when I make the same request with curl from the command-line, it works fine.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work, by using credentials instead of setting the Authorization headers explicitly:

```
NSURL                         *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:WLAPIBaseURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:email
                                                         password:password
                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

manager.credential = credential;
[manager GET:WLAPIEndpointMe parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 }];
```

I still do not understand why the headers were stripped out though...

Comment: you found an another way out, but it wasn't really the solution of the problem, why 'Authorization header not included in request'. I'm facing the same problem. Did you find any clue afterwards?